# How would I build an LDAP query for AD that returns all users in a particular security group whose accounts are not disabled?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

How would I build an LDAP query for AD that returns all users in a particular security group whose accounts are not disabled?

I tried

> (&(objectClass=person)(!(userAccountControl=*ACCOUNTDISABLE*)))

but that doesn’t seem to work.

I’m attempting to setup Google Apps Directory Sync and would like it to sync all users that are part of the “Google Apps Users” security group whose accounts are not disabled (or optionally, just suspend accounts in GA if they are disabled in AD).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works!

```
(&(memberOf=CN=Google Apps Users,DC=bbc,DC=pri)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))
```

Comment: I had to delete the extra set of parenthesis to get this to work, as Tony Roth suggested below.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes a set of yes/no values is stored in a single value by setting various bits. You can use a **bitmask** to check if they are set.

For example, 546 in decimal is the binary value 10 0010 0010 - in decimal, the sum of 512, 32, and 2. (All those numbers are powers of 2, which means they only have one '1' in their binary representation): That means those three yes/no values are set.

According to the [userAccountControl docs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144) that means the following values are set:

```
NORMAL_ACCOUNT (512)
PASSWD_NOTREQD (32)
ACCOUNTDISABLE (2)
```

However, for example, if you had a user who did not have `PASSWD_NOTREQD` set (so their userAccountControl value was 512), or one who also had `DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD` (65536) set (meaning their value was 66082), you would not find those users in your query.

What you need to do is use a [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29#Querying_the_status_of_a_bit) in order to query the value of only that bit:

```
10 0010 0010
00 0000 0010
------------
00 0000 0010
```

If the value for that bit is 1, then that bit is set. It doesn't matter what the other bits are set to, so you are effectively asking if `userAccountControl & 2 == 2`.

The LDAP syntax for checking a bit using AND is 1.2.840.113556.1.4.803, therefore you can see if the `ACCOUNTDISABLE` bit is set with (userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2). Adding (!(foo)) around it gives you all the users who are *not* disabled.

Comment: "(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)" is what i ended up using, you can see that in the accepted answer

Comment: I am aware of that, but I wanted to point out to any future people who might find this page, why sysadmin1138's answer was incomplete.

Comment: Kudos for the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this will work, but it won't pick up nested group members:

```
(&
    (memberOf=CN=GApsUsers,DN=....)
    (!(userAccountControl=546))
)
```

Comment: ok, "(&(memberOf=CN=Google Apps Users,DC=bbc,DC=pri)(!(userAccountControl=546)))" works, but it still returns users who have been disabled

I have two people in that group, one of them is disabled, but GADS is retrieving 2 user accounts from that LDAP query.

Comment: Ok, did some googleing, and found something that works for the account control “(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))”

Comment: This is what I ended up going with. (&(memberOf=CN=Google Apps Users,DC=bbc,DC=pri)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))

Comment: You should do a bitwise AND on bit 2 for 'account disabled', rather than checking the userAccountControl value in total; other bits might be set.

Comment: @crb - What? explain further please?

Comment: I'll give an answer, as it's too complicated to put in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

close but

(&(objectClass=person)(!(userAccountControl=ACCOUNTDISABLE)))

should be

(&(objectClass=person)(!userAccountControl=ACCOUNTDISABLE))

please note that I can't really test this from where I'm at!